# Access used values in a combine-operator-chain

Tags: swift, combine

I wonder if it is possible to access values in a combine-operator-chain that are used further up in the chain.

For example, if you have an array of strings, and you download a resource with each string, is it possible to access the string itself?

Maybe a pseudo-code example will help understand better:

```
let strings = ["a", "b", "c"]

strings.publisher
    .compactMap{ str in
        URL(string: "https://someresource/\(str)")
    }
    .flatMap { url  in
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    }
    .map { $0.data}
    .map { data in
        // here I would need the "str" string from above
    }
```

Help is much appreciated

Thx, Gregor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer that Jake wrote and deleted is correct. I don't know why he deleted it; maybe he felt he couldn't support it with example code. But the answer is exactly right. If you need the initial `str` value later in the pipeline, it is up to *you* to keep passing it down through every step. You typically do that by passing a *tuple* of values at each stage, so that the string makes it far enough down the chain to be retrieved. This is a *very* common strategy in Combine programming.

For a simple example, take a look at the Combine code in the central section of this article:

https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-5-asynchronous-looping-with-async-await/

As I say in the article:

> You’ll observe that, as opposed to GCD where local variables just magically “fall through” to nested completion handlers at a lower level of scope, every step in a Combine pipeline must explicitly pass down all information that may be needed by a later step. This can result in some rather ungainly values working their way down the pipeline, often in the form of a tuple, as I’ve illustrated here.
>
> But I don’t regard that as a problem. On the contrary, being explicit about what’s passing down the pipeline seems to me to be a gain in clarity.

To illustrate further, here's a rewrite of your pseudo-code; this is real code, you can run it and try it out:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let strings = ["a", "b", "c"]
        let pipeline = strings.publisher
            .map { str -> (String, URL) in
                let url = URL(string: "https://www.apeth.com/pep/manny.jpg")!
                return (str, url)
            }
            .flatMap { (str, url) -> AnyPublisher<(String, (data: Data, response: URLResponse)), URLError> in
                let sess = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                let just = Just(str).setFailureType(to: URLError.self)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                let zip = just.zip(sess).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                return zip
            }
            .map { (str, result) -> (String, Data) in
                (str, result.data)
            }
            .sink { comp in print(comp) } receiveValue: { (str, data) in print (str, data) }
        pipeline.store(in: &storage)
    }
}
```

That's not the only way to express the pipeline, but it does work, and it should give you a starting point.

Comment: I actually struggled with the flatMap part of the chain. Creating a Just publisher and zip it to the other one seems to do the trick. I'll try it out! Thx!

Comment: Yeah, it may be difficult to work out for any particular variant of the pipeline, but it's what you have to do: just keep passing the needed values down the pipeline, somehow, so that they are present later when you want them.